# Missing value for AzureWebJobsStorage in local.settings.json

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I got this error message when trying to run locally. Before this no issue at all.

```
Missing value for AzureWebJobsStorage in local.settings.json. This is required for all triggers other than httptrigger, kafkatrigger. You can run 'func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <functionAppName>' or specify a connection string in local.settings.json.
```

My local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't give the value of AzureWebJobsStorage.

local default value: `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`

The reason why you need to offer is because other than httptrigger, all other triggers needs to start storage emulator first.